# flight rescheduling charges for Indigo?

Tags: air-travel, india, bookings, domestic-travel, indigo

In Indigo there is a Flex option which I don't know what it stands for ?

Apparently it stands so that one can reschedule the flights as well. But I was told at the gate that full fare would be needed to reschedule the flight which is/was confusing.

To take an example -

Let's say I have a flight on 10th December 2018 from Cochin to Pune, (COK to Pune) 6E 337 . I already booked the flight for say INR 3000/- which includes the flex option (INR 1000) . See charges

https://www.goindigo.in/information/fees-and-charges.html

Now I want to prepone my travel to 3rd December 2018 . I was told that I may have to again full charges which seems absurd suggestion. This happened at a recent flight and I had to buy a new flight ticket altogether and then come back and cancel the flight.

Just for reference I saw this news item on the same topic 3 years back.

https://www.business-standard.com/article/companies/indigo-to-allow-multiple-rescheduling-at-rs-1-500-extra-115051901062_1.html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Did you check the fare difference? At the gate would be too late and, while there is no fee to change, you would be charged the fare difference for the week-earlier flight. The [IndiGo Flexi Fare Terms and Conditions](https://www.goindigo.in/add-on-services/flexi-fares.html?linkNav=flexi-fares_header) outline the fare offer (added emphasis mine):

> Our all new Flexi Fares are attractive providing flexibility to make unlimited changes to travel dates without incurring **Change Fee**. This Fare is just right for the customer who wants flexibility and comfort in their travel.
>
> - Unlimited changes can be made to a booking where there will be no change fee **however, the applicable fare difference would be charged**
> - Cancellation Fees for Domestic travel is Rs 3000 and Rs 4500 for International travel
> - **Changes can be made to a booking upto 2 hours prior for domestic flights and 4 hours prior for international flights**